# Matching columns of two datasets

Tags: r

I've been assigned this problem where I need to match mobile apps and publishers between two data sets (One is GooglePlay, the other is iTunes).

Here is a description of the variables used in the iTunes dataset (The Google Play data set variables names are similair or the same).

```
anon_ios_app_id: anonymized iOS app id

anon_ios_publisher_id: anonymized iOS publisher id

points: the “worth” of the match, 10 points is highest worth and 0.5 is the lowest.

ios_name: name of the mobile app in the itunes store

ios_publisher_name: name of the publisher of the app in the itunes store

category_name: the category of the app

type: Game or Non-game
```

I've done some analysis to look for the names of apps in the data sets that share the same name and publishers. As an example, I searched for apps that had "Walmart" in their names.

```
GooglePlay <- read.csv("...\\GooglePlay.csv", header = TRUE)
iTunes <- read.csv("...\\iTunes.csv", header = TRUE)

grep("Walmart", iTunes$ios_name)
[1]  41203  51026  63522  64330 112441 113516 115510 117588 117788 119558 119605 120002 165514 248817
[15] 277425 290010 463244 546799 565806
grep("Walmart", GooglePlay$gp_name)
[1]    154  31984 162284 162342 162792 168722 168774 169339 325520 325601 357122 360050 436084 437144
[15] 441458 447177 503260
```

During my analysis, I did find that some apps had the same name and publisher in both data sets. For example

```
GooglePlay$gp_name[154]
[1] Walmart Photo
GooglePlay$gp_publisher_name[154]
[1] Kodak Alaris Inc.
iTunes$ios_name[165514]
[1] Walmart Photo
iTunes$ios_publisher_name[165514]
[1] Kodak Alaris Inc.
```

My objectives are:  1. Provide one unified file with all the respective id’s/names of the matched apps/publishers. 
2. provide one number: the SUM(iOS points + GP points) for the matched apps.

What functions should I use to match apps and publishers from the two data sets? How do I make a unified file of those matches?

Comment: Are you familiar with`cbind` and `rbind`? You know how to subset on a dataframe, like `iTunes[iTunes$ios_name == "Walmart"]` which will return the rows of `iTunes` where the condition in the `[]` is `TRUE`.

Comment: @ShawnMehan `iTunes[iTunes$ios_name == "Walmart", ]` for data.frames. Your code will work for data.tables.

Comment: Yep, missed the `, `. This will add **all columns**.

Comment: @ShawnMehan @Imo Hey guys, I edited my question to show you the outputs. I'm trying to get all the apps and publishers in the two datasets that match. As the outputs show: `GooglePlay$gp_name[154]` and `iTunes$ios_name[165514]` produce the app with the name "Walmart Photo".  The outputs for  `GooglePlay$gp_publisher_name[154]` and `iTunes$ios_publisher_name[165514]` produce the publisher "Kodak Alaris Inc". I'm not interested in all the matches with the name "Walmart"

Comment: Look into `merge()`.